# Error extending Laravel's abstract TestCase class (error is saying that my extended class must be abstract)

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm hoping somebody out there can help me. I am using laravel 4 and I'm writing my first unit tests for a while but am running into trouble. I'm trying to extend the TestCase class but I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class registrationTest contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::createApplication) in /home/john/www/projects/MyPainChart.com/app/tests/registrationTest.php on line 4
```

Now if I have this right then the error is referring to the fact that is a method is abstract then the class it's in must also be abstract. As you can see from below the TestCase class it is abstract. I have searched for this error but have drawn a blank.

Trying to follow this cast on Laracasts https://laracasts.com/lessons/tdd-by-example and although you have to be a subscriber to watch the video the file is underneath it and as you can see I am doing nothing different to Jeffrey Way.

My Test:

```
<?php

class registrationTests extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{

    /**
     * Make sure the registration page loads
     * @test
     */
    public function make_sure_the_registration_page_loads_ok()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

The beginning of the TestCase class:

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Testing;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

abstract class TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
```

By the way - the Laravel testing class is not autoloaded by default and so I have tried both the fully qualified class name and use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing and then just extending TestCase. I know it can see it aswhen I don't fully qualify the name it complains that the class cannot be found. I've also tried:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and

```
composer update
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 8):

According to your error message: `Class registrationTest contains 1 abstract method` the `Base Class` contains an `abstract method` and when a `Child Class` extends another class with abstract methods then the child class should implement the abstract methods available in `Base class`. So, `registrationTest` is child class and  `\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` is the base class and it contains an abstract method:

### An abstract method in `\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`:

```
abstract public function createApplication();
```

So, in your `child class/registrationTest` you must implement this method:

```
public function createApplication(){
    //...
}
```

But, actually you don't need to directly extend the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` because in `app/tests` folder there is a class `TestCase/TestCase.php` and you can extend this class instead:

```
// In app/tests folder
class registrationTest extends TestCase {
    //...
}
```

The `TestCase.php` class looks like this:

```
class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

public function createApplication()
{
        $unitTesting = true;
        $testEnvironment = 'testing';
        return require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
    }
}
```

Notice that, `TestCase` has implemented that abstract method `createApplication` so you don't need to extend it in your class. You should use `TestCase` class as base class to create test cases. So, create your tests in `app/tests` folder and create classes like:

```
class registrationTest extends TestCase {
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
    }
}
```

Read [Class Abstraction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Comment: Thanks - you are a star. Earlier today I made the mistake of thinking that PHPSpec was a replacement for PHPunit and not to be used alongside (I now know the truth) but in my haste I deleted the tests dir and therefore the TestCase.php file. I also deleted the file from composer.json. It was only when I realised that I need both that I re-created the dir.

Thanks to git all is well again.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Firstly go in composer.json and add

```
"scripts" : {"test" : "vendor/bin/phpunit"
    }
```

**Then run composer update**
Then

The **TestCase.php** class in path */test/* should look like

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase {
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

Then your  **registrationTests** class should look like this

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class registrationTests extends TestCase {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just intake dependancy at the top of your class as follows and you are good to go,

```
<?php

namespace YOUR_CLASS_PATH;

use Tests\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase{
     ...//your business logic here
}
```

I hope this works.